# Prism Js not highlighting css

Tags: javascript, css

I followed instructions from official Prism docs and entered the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="themes/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <pre><code class="language-css">p { color: red }</code></pre>
<script src="prism.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it's not highlighting p { color: red },  What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
p { color: red ; }
```

You forgot the final semicolon

Comment: Is your ```prism.js``` placed at folder that you indicates?

Comment: Try with ```<pre><code class="language-markup">&lt;p class="blue">TEXT &lt;/p></code></pre>``` to check another tag. If it doesn't work try placing ```<script...``` at the start of body. Just to check if you are getting prism.js correctly

Comment: @bs5alpha Then I'm surely there are something in the implementation process of library that you are forgotten or doing wrong.. Don't forget to reply with an answer if you solve this :)